# Not able to locate FactoryRegistry class when using GeoTools

Tags: java, shapefile, geotools

I am trying to load and parse a shapefile using the GeoTools library. However, when I try to load the file the following call is resulting is a dependency failure for `org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry`:

```
DataStore newStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(connect);
```

Error:

```
org/geotools/factory/FactoryRegistry
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/geotools/factory/FactoryRegistry
```

I have included the following dependencies in gradle:

```
compile files ('libs/geotools/gt-opengis-14.2.jar')
compile files ('libs/geotools/gt-api-14.2.jar')
compile files ('libs/geotools/gt-shapefile-14.2.jar')
compile files ('libs/geotools/gt-cql-14.2.jar')
compile files ('libs/geotools/gt-main-14.2.jar')
compile files ('libs/geotools/gt-referencing-14.2.jar')
compile files ('libs/geotools/gt-epsg-hsql-14.2.jar')
```

I am not sure if all of them are needed but none of them have the missing class. Is there any other dependency I am missing? The class is documented [here](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/factory/FactoryRegistry.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy answer to this problem is to use Maven to manage your dependencies, this would then automatically pull in `gt-metadata` for you and solve your problem.

If you must manage your dependencies by hand then the I wrote a [blog post](http://blog.ianturton.com/geotools/maven/dependencies/2015/04/15/FindingGeoToolsJars.html) that describes how to use [oops](https://code.google.com/p/joops/) to search the GeoTools jars for a class.

Comment: Thanks. I added `gt-metadata`. That solved this problem but now I am getting other similar errors for other classes. I know using Maven (or Gradle) to manage dependencies would solve this. But these dependencies are not found in the repo. I have seen other people report the same problem but none of the solutions proposed work for me.

Comment: What sort of store are you trying to connect to?

Comment: Tried quite a few. Latest one is http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/. But that seems to be inconsistent. Different dependencies are reported missing at different times. Right now the missing one is `Could not find jai_core.jar (javax.media:jai_core:1.1.3)`.

Comment: Fixed. Gradle was looking for `jai_core` from `mavenCentral`. Moving `mavenCentral` after `osgeo` in repository list fixed it.